# Xcode 9.3 IOS simulator screenshot always give same dimensions

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode9.3

I want to take screenshot of IOS app for App store submit. But the saved screenshot image dimensions is always 750 × 1334 no matter how i scale the size of simulator or change the iPhone model type, the outcome is always the same.

**Solution tried:**
Unchecked `Optimized Rendering for Window Size`, choose `Physical size` and save the screen shot with `cmd` + `s`.

I was try the solution above, but it is **not working** at all

Answer (score 3):

Use the iPhone Plus simulators to get your screenshots (e.g. iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 7 Plus, etc.). They will generate a 1242x2208 screenshot size. You are most likely using one of the non-plus simulators (e.g. the iPhone 6) since their screen size is 750x1334; they are NOT the 5.5" devices.